# How to foreach over map in TypeScript? Getting error code TS2349

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following map, mapping strings to arrays of any type:

```
public schedule : { [dayName: string]: any[] };
```

When I try to foreach over each key-value mapping:

```
this.schedule.forEach(dayName, day){...}
```

I get the following error:

TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `schedule` is not an array. It is an object that can be indexed with a string and that value will be of type `any[]`. See [documentation on indexable types.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

Perhaps you meant to loop it after accessing the index:

```
this.schedule["somekey"].forEach(...);
```

Or you if meant to loop over the keys of `schedule`, then use `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(this.schedule).forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `schedule` defined as simple object with string index signature, it lacks `forEach` method. However, it thinks that there's a `forEach` property in the object with `any[]` type. And it need isn't callable, hence the error.

To iterate over properties of an object you can use `Object.keys` function:

```
Object.keys(schedule).forEach((scheduleProp) => /* do something with schedule[scheduleProp] */);
```

Other way to achieve what you're after is to use `Map`:

```
public schedule: Map<string, any[]>;

// ...

schedule.forEach((value, key) => /* ... */);
```

Answer (score 1):

No Ecmascript version ever added a method `forEach` to Objects. It exists in Arrays.

The ES6's Maps do have a forEach method too, but what you have here is an object used as a Map.

There are many ways to iterate over an object's keys (and values), I will give you one:

```
Object.keys(this.schedule).forEach(dayName => console.log(this.schedule[dayName]))
```